# Dynamic Text from Checkboxes Value

Tags: jquery, html

Somebody please help me to get id from check-boxes and put it on `href` item with simple jQuery code?

```
<a href="edit?id=dynamicText">Edit</a>
<a href="delete?id=dynamicText">Delet</a>
```

After I clicked the check-boxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck" id="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck" id="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck" id="3">
```

Comment: you have to try some code at your end first. this is not a code writing platform. We help to correct your code what you have tried so far

Comment: on click of checkbox you want to put ids on href? ans what about multiple checkbox selected?

Comment: It would make more sense to use the `value` of the checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example to add ids when you check checkboxes. Let me know if this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $edit = $("#edit");

  $checkedBoxes = [];

  //for edit link only 
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e) {
    if (e.target.checked)
      $checkedBoxes.push(e.target.id);
    else
      $checkedBoxes.pop(e.target.id);
    $edit.attr('href', 'edit?id=' + $checkedBoxes.join('&'));
    console.log('href: ', $edit.attr('href'));
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="edit" href="edit?id=">Edit</a>
<a id="delete" href="delete?id=dynamicText">Delete</a>


<p>After I clicked the check-boxes</p>

<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck" id="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck" id="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck" id="3">
```